# JSF2 logs with tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, logging, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm having a project using JSF2 (2.1.2), Richfaces4 (4.0.0.Final) on tomcat6 (6.0.28). In order to manage portability between Tomcat and WebSphere7 for my EARs, I have the following jars inside my tomcat lib: el-api-2.2.jar, jsf-api-2.1.2.jar, jsf-impl-2.1.2.jar, validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar.

My problem is that I never managed to change the log levels of JSF or Richfaces and except from the initialization ones, I don't see any inside my console. Even when I get exceptions in my server response !

I tried several ways:

1) Inside my applications, I'm using slf4j and log4j. So the natural way would be to use SLF4JBridgeHandler.install(). I made a small servlet to call this method during its init() method and added a 'load-on-startup' to be sure it's loaded before JSF Servlet (I'm not sure tomcat cares at all about this load-on-startup directive because I still get logs from JSF init before), e.g.:

```
INFO: JSF1027 : [null] Les objets ELResolvers de JSF n’ont pas été enregistrés avec le conteneur JSP.
09-09-2011 16:50:58:591 [Thread-2] 937  DEBUG com.jsf.test.SLF4JBridgeHandlerInstallerServlet - SLF4JBridgeHandler.install() OK!
```

I also added some configuration in my log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="javax.faces"><level value="debug"/></logger>  
<logger name="com.sun.faces"><level value="debug"/></logger>
<logger name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf"><level value="debug"/></logger>
```

But I don't see any logs in my console when displaying a JSF page...
I also tried using a filter to call SLF4JBridgeHandler.install() before the execution of the JSF Servlet, but I only get a lot of OK logs from my filter...

2) I tried to follow the tutorial [here](http://java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-2-logging-with-tomcat) exactly (it creates new files in tomcat log folder for each logger of JSF2). I tried by changing the logging.properties inside the conf folder of tomcat and by adding a new logging.properties inside my src/resources/ folder in my application. But no luck...

3) I tried to add the JSF loggers to the the logging.properties inside my tomcat by adding this:

```
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean.level=FINEST
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config.level=FINEST
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.level=FINEST
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.resource.level=FINEST
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.resource.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle.level=FINEST
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

No luck yet...

4) I tried to use log4j inside tomcat instead of juli by following [this documentation](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/02/configure-log4j-on-tomcat.html). It seems to work well, but changing the resulting log4j.properties to put the JSF loggers in DEBUG didn't work...

Any idea ?

Regards,

Florian

Comment: Hi Florian, Currently I am trying to configure JSF logging and I have already tried this example provided by you, but unable to do it, I am trying to log it in a LOG-FILE rather then console, can you suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Two facts:

- JSF uses [`java.util.logging`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) API which is to be configured by a `logging.properties` file in the root of the runtime classpath.
- The `logging.properties` file of the currently(!) running runtime environment (JRE) will be used.

If you're running Tomcat from inside an IDE like Eclipse, then Tomcat's own `logging.properties` won't be used. The one in `JDK/JRE/lib` will be used where "JDK" is the JDK install folder such as `jdk1.6.0_23`. If you'd like to explicitly specify the location of the `logging.properties` file, then you would need to set a VM argument:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/tomcat/logging.properties
```

Regardless of the logging file used, in order to enable Mojarra logging, you need to open the `logging.properties` template file in question, scroll to the bottom and edit the following line near the bottom

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
```

into

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

so that the **global** console level is set to `ALL` instead of `INFO`. Otherwise lower levels than `INFO` just won't be logged at all.

Finally add the following two lines to the very bottom of the file

```
javax.faces.level = ALL
com.sun.faces.level = ALL
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.level = ALL
```

The first turns on all JSF API logging, the second turns on all JSF impl (Mojarra) logging, and the third turns on all JSF Java EE logging.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing: the fast that tomcat uses the Eclipse logging.properties when launched inside Eclipse. Thanks!

The only remaining problem is that the SLF4JBridgeHandler doesn't seems to work at all even after that... 
I have a nice servlet to configure the logging levels of log4j on the fly and it would have been nice to be able to change the JSF ones...