# JSF: Increasing logging level for Tomcat 7 within Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, logging

I'm getting very frustrated with JSF development using Tomcat 7 within Eclipse (or more specifically, Spring Tool Suite 2.8.1).

JSF backing beans and accompanying xHtml pages inexplicably break without any logging.

I have attempted to increase the logging level within Tomcat 7, but it appears that "another" Tomcat 7 runs within my Eclipse workspace?

It is possible to increase the log output from a JSF application running within an embedded Tomcat 7 within Eclipse to debug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2 logs with tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363704/jsf2-logs-with-tomcat)

Comment: By the way, just posting a question about the concrete problem along with a fullworthy SSCCE will likely generate faster answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem by:

- Configuring my application to use lo4j
- Attaching a RollingFileAppender to the root logger in a log4j.properties file