# Change Tomcat default log severity

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

My Tomcat 7 is logging messages like these in the standard output's:

```
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
31/05/2012 15:58:59 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
```

But I need to log only WARN and ERROR messages.

Is there anyway to set this?

Comment: This particular log is not coming from JSF. It's coming from Tomcat. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually, it would be very interesting if I could change to WARN JSF's logging either. Things like `INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor WebApplication1.xml 31/05/2012 16:48:48 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized` are polluting the output.

Comment: For that, check this dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363704/jsf2-logs-with-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties <-- change this file and i guess you need this setting

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO

Comment: Apparently you're using Tomcat in an IDE.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Tomcat inside Netbeans, but I'm changing logging.properties from catalina base.