# Hiding JSF1064 messages

Tags: jsf, logging, resources, logback

```
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, masthead/pic.jpg, from library, img.
Aug 3, 2013 10:18:16 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: 
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

How can I hide these warning from the logs?
I'm using logback.

Comment: Not sure about logback. But, I guess if you set your bin logs in Error mode, then this warning will not get printed..

Comment: @BalusC can you make this an answer so I can reward you the bounty? Also why does this get logged through JULI and not by logback like everything else in my app? (Sorry not that clued about how logging frameworks work!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those logs are not logged via Logback. They are logged via Java SE's builtin `java.util.logging` interfaces. JULI loggers are configurable via `JRE/lib/logging.properties` where `JRE` is the folder holding the Java Runtime Environment. In your specific case, you just need to add the following line to the end of file in order to bring it one level up so that warnings are suppressed.

```
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.level = SEVERE
```

#### See also:

- [JSF2 logs with tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363704/jsf2-logs-with-tomcat/7364065#7364065)

Comment: Glassfish seems to not use (or override) this JRE logger level. It can be changed into `<glassfish_root>/domains/<domain_name>/config/logging.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

To manage messages from a certain package you must define an specific logger, and set the level higher than the messages you want to hide.

As an example, to avoid the WARNING messages from com.sun.faces and its sub packeges, you must include the next logger definition at the LogBack configuration file:

```
  <logger name="com.sun.faces" level="ERROR" />
```

Reference: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Anyway, you shuold check why your JSF engine is showing these messages, and fix it. Perhaps your web.xml lacks some servlet mapping for `masthead/*`?

Comment: No, they are just shown because the client aborted the resource request (for example, when pressing Esc or hastily navigating away while loading a page referencing those resources, even a thunder strike on client's machine while loading the page would cause this). However, knowing that is generally not interesting and only log pollution.

Comment: The error messages don't appear to be produced by logback as they have a different format from all my other logback messages