# Deployment of WAR (JSF) on tomcat with IntelliJ takes longer

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment

I'm working on a JSF project and for developing I deploy the exploded war locally in a tomcat.
Since some days the deployment takes tremendously longer than before (lets say 2 min vs 12 min).
I can't remember that I changed something beside from the application code.

What can I do to determine whats taking time during the deployment?

From the output I see some interesting lines here:

```
...
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 17, 2016 1:47:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 17, 2016 1:47:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jun 17, 2016 1:47:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 17, 2016 1:47:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 17, 2016 1:54:55 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/fwf-web'
Jun 17, 2016 1:55:03 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Jun 17, 2016 1:55:12 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Jun 17, 2016 1:55:12 PM org.primefaces.extensions.application.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 3.0.0
[2016-06-17 01:55:36,359] Artifact fwf-web:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-06-17 01:55:36,360] Artifact fwf-web:war exploded: Deploy took 519.951 milliseconds
```

1) The line `Jun 17, 2016 1:54:55 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized` seems to take longer ( ~7 min since last time log)
but I don't know why or how to get further information.

2) I don't really understand the `... is already defined` and what I can do against it (but these lines were there also before the problem)

3) As I'm new to Java/tomcat/JSF I don't know what/where to investigate next ...

Comment: Turn on `ALL` logging as per http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363704, then you can investigate.