# How to increase tomcat logging detail

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm currently working with a Tomcat 9.0 application running on JDK 17 that experiences a startup delay of about three minutes. I'm looking to identify the processes occurring prior to the "Deploy took xxx milliseconds" log message to optimize performance.

Following the guidance provided in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363704/jsf2-logs-with-tomcat), I've set all logging levels to ALL in the logging.properties file located at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf, but it hasn't yielded the desired level of detail in the logs.

Additionally, for the purpose of testing, I'd like to ensure that all SQL queries executed during startup are logged. The goal is to pinpoint any bottlenecks during initialization. Below is an example of the current logging output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Could someone assist me with advice on how to configure Tomcat or the underlying application to provide more detailed logging? This would specifically include the activities leading up to the deploy message and the SQL queries being executed during startup.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: for sql logging you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491028/175554 for oracle and if you are using different DB you can check [p6spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242910/175554) for the application itself you need to check is it using log4j or logback and related logging configurations.